# Library lookup paths in java

Tags: java

the question which is a problem whenever somebody is deploying an application: where does java look for it libraries (jars and dlls) after a project got deployed?

Best regards,
Stefan

Comment: Be more specific, please: what is a *project*, what is *deploying*, both in the context of your question!

Comment: no, this question should be answered in a generic way,which applies for 99% of the developed applications!

Comment: to be more precise: *project* and *deploying* in a J2EE context is different from doing the same with a simple Java application or an applet. And *project* could be an IDE related term (like: eclipse project).

Comment: but i really hope, that all of this projects share a pattern, how you deploy their libraries! or a least methods to get where they look for their libraries....

Comment: under the hood, yes. A java virtual machine has one classpath String that lists paths and libraries - although, a `ClassLoader` can use other mechanics to locate a classfile - outside of a directory on the path. And from a user/developers perspective, the *pattern* is set by the target environment (applet, executable jar, application server, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On its [classpath](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html).

On application servers there are usually quite a number of paths set up already.  You can usually check the startup logs or log the value of the following property to determine where its looking:

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

Comment: .. which is not true for native libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It looks a couple of different places as the other answers have suggested. You can use the `System.getProperty("java.library.path")` or `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` to see the actual paths.

The code below I also found quite useful. You can use it to add at runtime a path to the library paths that get searched.

```
    /**
     * Allows you to add a path to the library path during runtime
     * @param dllLocation The path you would like to add
     * @return True if the operation completed successfully, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean addDllLocationToPath(final String dllLocation)
    {
        //our return value
        boolean retVal = false;
        try
        {
            System.setProperty("java.library.path", System.getProperty("java.library.path") + ";" + dllLocation);
            //get the sys path field
            Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
            fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);
            fieldSysPath.set(null, null);
            retVal = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Could not modify path");
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29

**The virtual machine searches for and loads classes in this order:

```
bootstrap classes: the classes that are fundamental to the Java Platform (comprising the public classes of the Java Class Library, and the private classes that are necessary for this library to be functional).
extension classes: packages that are in the extension directory of the JRE or JDK, jre/lib/ext/
user-defined packages and libraries
```

**